# Browser not receiving cookie

Tags: node.js, express

I've been taking Jonas' Backend course with Node.js, Express.js, and MongoDB. When I reached the server-side rendering part, I had to send a JWT (JSON web token) in the response when a user logs in or signs up. I should send the JWT via a cookie, but I think there is something wrong in my code, and I can't find it.

When I use Postman to send a request, the cookie is received with the JWT successfully. I also tried to make a separate route that sends cookies, and the browser receives the cookie with no errors.

Code that sends the token:

```
const signToken = (id) => jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN });

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = signToken(user._id);

    const cookieOptions = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        httpOnly: true,
    };

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        cookieOptions.secure = true;
    }

    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

    user.password = undefined; // Remove passwords from the output
    res.status(statusCode).json({
        status: 'success',
        token,
        data: { user },
    });
};
```

Login function:

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body; // Destructuring

    // Check if email and pass exist
    if (!email || !password) {
        return next(new AppError('Either email or password is incorrect', 400));
        // We say return because we want to make sure that this function finishes right away
    }

    // Check if user exists and password is correct
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password'); // Include password in the query only this time (+password)

    // Check if the user typed the password correctly
    if (!(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password)) || !user) {
        return next(new AppError('Either email or password is incorrect', 401)); // 401 = unauthorized
    }

    // If everything is okay, send data to the client

    // Create a token for logging in
    createSendToken(user, 200, res);
});
```

Front-end code:

```
export const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const result = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/login',
            data: {
                email,
                password,
            },
        });

        console.log(res);

        if (result.data.status === 'success') {
            showAlert('success', 'Logged in successfully!');
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.assign('/');
            }, 1500);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
    }
};
```